# How to auto-indent / format groovy script with ACE or CodeMirror

Tags: groovy, codemirror, ace-editor, auto-indent, autoformatting

I'm developing a web app which needs an embedded groovy script editor, i tried both with CodeMirror and ACE but neither offers me auto-indent nor formatting.

I fetch the code of the script from the database and then put it on a javascript variable called *myScript*; 
Then with ACE i do this:

```
    var editor = ace.edit("editor");
    editor.setTheme("ace/theme/monokai");
    editor.getSession().setMode("ace/mode/groovy");
    editor.getSession().setUseWrapMode(true);
    editor.setShowPrintMargin(false);
    editor.setValue(myScript);
```

and i do it like this with CodeMirror:

```
      var myCodeMirror = CodeMirror(document.body, {
      value: myScript,
      mode:  "groovy",
      theme: "monokai",
      lineWrapping: true,
      lineNumbers: true
    });
```

and the editor works perfect, the problem is that the code that it shows it is not indented nor formatted, and it's pretty ugly. For example:

> def reputationMapping = []; def totalReputation = 0; def userReputationResult = message.properties['reputation'];  for (row in userReputationResult) {    reputationMapping[row[0]] = row[1];     totalReputation = row[1]; };  def computedRank = 0; def reviewResult = message.properties['reviews'];     for (row in reviewResult) {   if (reputationMapping[row[0]] != null) {        def reputation = reputationMapping[row[0]];         computedRank = computedRank + (reputation * row[1]);    }; }; message.payload = computedRank;

Can you please help? Thanks.

Comment: did you manage to get this resolved?